# Box2D Python using Visual Studio

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-2017, box2d, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am new to Box2D, first of all I want to apologize for maybe trivial question.
I have understood that it is written in C++ but it can be used with various different languages. I need to use it with Python, ideally with MS Visual Studio 2017 (but Idle or Canopy will do).

I was able to build Box2D to Visual Studio but I do not know how to run it using Python, could you please help me (a step-by-step solution would be really appreciated).

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [PyBox2D](https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d) which is a binding to original library.
There are prebuilt package but it is a conda package you can install it with 3 steps:

1. Install miniconda3. Download it from [here](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html)
2. Create a new environment (named py34 here) and activate it:

```
$ conda create -n py34 python=3.4

$ source activate py34
```

3. Install Box2D from the repo author:

```
$ conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/kne pybox2d
```

If you want to build from source (library author only suggests if you want to latest features or if you want to help development) here is the [guide](https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/blob/master/INSTALL.md#building-from-source-windows)

Disclaimer: These steps are taken from the github repo itself

Comment: I did as you wrote and then I tried to execute one of PyBox2D examples and this error was shown: `File C:\User\...\examples\cantilever.py, line 21, in <module> from .framework import (Framework, main) ValueError:Attempted relative import in non-package` I also used the alternative approach from the guide you sent me (It says it can be done using MS Visual Studio, which I prefer) The guide told me to download SWIG, but it did not work (neither with anaconda nor with Visual Studio).

Comment: I mean, I downloaded the SWIG succesfully, of course, but still after I followed the rest of the steps i was not able to run the examples...